# Adding rasters to mosaic dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, mosaic

I'm working with an ArcSDE geodatabase v 10.0 in SQL Server 2008R2.
I added more than a dozen of rasters w/o problem.

Server: WIN 2008R2 12GB RAM
SPACE: 1TB
Created a mosaic dataset (empty) w/o problem.

My gis client is ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.
Previously changed raster storage to ST_RASTER.

Now I reverted this change and put raster storage back to SDEBINARY

Problem:
I cannot add any rasters to the mosaic dataset; not even a raster dataset inside the sde gdb itself.
I tried this many times, using python, different clients: one with standard, and advanced licenses... no results.
ArcGIS just crashes w/o any information, even when adding only one image.

Comment: This sounds like something for Esri Support

Comment: The first law of storing rasters in enterprise geodatabases is: Don't do it.
The second law (for experts only) is: Don't do it yet.  There aren't any use cases where filling a terabyte of transaction logs is a recommended practice.  File-based rasters are faster and more efficient with storage, and can be backed up with filesystem backup tools.  While Tech Support may be able to unravel your storage issue, I'd recommend rolling back to scratch and using file-based raster storage.